# ¿Como crear un sistema de mensajes de combate?

Tags: unity3d, facebook-api, unity

Hola mi problema es que me veo en la necesidad de implementar un servicio de envio y recepción de mensajes entre el usuario emisor y al azar a un receptor que se encuentre en linea estilo Clash Royale, para luego pasar al proceso de creacion de una Room en Photon y combatir,  pero ninguno de los servicios online de Facebook y PlayFab (estos son los que estoy utilizando) me permite cumplir mi mision (de acuerdo a la investigacion que realice), también pense en usar el ChatClient de Photon, pero este no permite detectar los canales de chat actuales (¿verdad?). Y como ven me encuentro muy atascado, pero tengo fe en que me ayudaran a salir de este embrollo.

Disculpen mi falta de código,  pero no tengo idea de como implementar mi idea en un codigo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion mas factible que pude encontrar fue utilizar un metodo de Photon llamado JoinRandomRoom() el cual voy a implementar en un boton y cuando el usuario pise en este se conectara a un Room existente que cumpla con las propiedades y si no existe este creara uno para que luego otro usuario se conecte y cumpla el total de usuarios conectados y pase a la escena de combate esta es mi idea.

El codigo que implementare lo encontre en el [foro de unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/pun-joinrandomroom-not-working-with-custom-properties.367077/)